# Disable Right to left support on IOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, right-to-left

I have a large multi language app that does not have auto layout yet. The app contains many default tableview cells. In Arabic the app stays left to right and only uses the arabic localized strings. Is there a way to turn off this new right-to-left support so that default tableviewcells and navigation controller buttons are not flipped?

Answer (score 0):

I know this approach via autolayout... in autolayout you can disable right to left change by selecting particular constraint and in property inspector untick the lable which says respect language...